# Xposed - I can print inner class methods, but method hooking doesn't work

Tags: android, xposed

I'm trying to hook a method in inner class, but nothing happen, while I can print all the methods of that class.

All of the logs printed except which is in the `replaceHookedMethod`.

```
public class Keyguard implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {

    @Override
    public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {

        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.keyguard"))
            return;
        XposedBridge.log("we are in keyguard!");

        Class HwClockView = XposedHelpers.findClass("com.android.keyguard.AbsClockView$HwClockView",
                lpparam.classLoader);
        for (Method m : HwClockView.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            XposedBridge.log("method: " + m.getName());
        }

        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(HwClockView, "getDateString",
                TimeZone.class, new XC_MethodReplacement() {
            @Override
            protected Object replaceHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                XposedBridge.log("we are in getDateString!");
                return String.format("%s", Utils.getPersianDateShort());
            }
        });
}
```

**Update:**
After second comment changed code to this, but same as before nothing happens:

```
public class Keyguard implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {

    @Override
    public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) {

        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.keyguard"))
            return;
        XposedBridge.log("we are in keyguard!");

        Class HwClockView = XposedHelpers.findClass("com.android.keyguard.AbsClockView$HwClockView",
                lpparam.classLoader);
        for (Method m : HwClockView.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            XposedBridge.log("method: " + m.getName());
            if ("getDateString".equalsIgnoreCase(m.getName())) {
                XposedBridge.hookMethod(m, new XC_MethodReplacement() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object replaceHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) {
                        XposedBridge.log("we are in getDateString!");
                        return String.format("%s", Utils.getPersianDateShort());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
}
```

Target class:

```
public class AbsClockView extends RelativeLayout {
    protected Calendar mCalendar;
    private HwCustKeyguardStatusViewEx mCustKeyguardStatusViewEx;
    protected TextView mDateView;
    protected TextView mDescriptionView;
    protected Factory mFactory;
    protected final AtomicBoolean mFixedTimeZone;
    protected FrameLayout mTimeParent;
    protected TextView mTimeView;

    public interface Factory {
        void refreshDate();

        void setHwDateFormat();

        void updateHwTimeStyle();
    }

    private class HwClockView implements Factory {
        protected Context mContext;

        public HwClockView(Context context) {
            ...
        }

        private CharSequence getDateString(TimeZone timeZone) {
            return someString;
        }
    }

    public AbsClockView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have the source code of the hooked app, therefore don't make the mistake and assume that the compiled code is identical to the source code! Compilers optimized the code therefore simple private getter methods my be just inlined and then converted to a read field command. Instead use the APK file and decompile it using a decompiler like Jadx to see what actual code has been generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Robert Thanks but there is no source code, I used Jadx and the code is for Keyguard package from Huawei EMUI4.0

Comment: `findAndHookMethod` is just a wrapper. If you already have the method you can simply call `XposedBridge.hookMethod(method, callback);` Just look at the source code of `findAndHookMethod`. Anyway are you really sure `getDateString` is called somewhere in the app code?

Comment: I think I did it as you said, but result was the same as before, anyway I'm migrated from EMUI to Lineage 16.0 now and I don't need to find what's going on anymore.